# Click a button and echo the related php file in the body of the same page

Tags: php, echo

I have tried numerous codes and all without avail. If the user was to click (button)New Starter (/button) I would like it to echo the file new.php within the same page and if the user was then to select resignation it should then replace new.php with resign.php

```
<"new.php"><button>New Starter</button></a>
 <"resign.php"><button>Resignation</button></a> 
<"promo.php"><button>Promotion</button></a>
```

So the idea is that it displays relevant information upon the button click on the same page

This php displays a text only file and echos no problem but incorporating it into onclick or within the button is causing the page to go blank or show the related file upon each other

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('new.php'); ?>


<button on click echo $abc="new.php";}>New Starter</button>
<?php {echo $abc; } ?>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly apreciated

Comment: does not work **HOW**?

Comment: ??? Nowhere near enough inforamtion to be able to understand what you are actually doing or trying to do!

Comment: I think you need to reconsider the question, it is difficult to understand at all.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with PHP alone. They keywords to search for are: JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thank you! I have researched into it and have a code that is working on one file. Now with a bit of tinkering I will hopefully have it for each one I require! - Not quite sure how to add the code for others who may have the same problems...

Answer (score 2):

```
<head><script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","new.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
```

Then in the body

```
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Test</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Test</button>
```